# Good Technology Resources for a Pre-Algebra Class?

Tags: soft-question, education, math-software

I am looking for some recommendations for good and interesting technology resources for a pre-algebra class.  My main goal is to allow the students to be able to self-pace the instruction,  out of class.

Do you have an recommendations for resources that can be used? Any tips/experiences on the implementation of those resources?

Comment: This is too vague. What is taught in the course? What kind of resources are you thinking of?

Comment: The course follows the [common core standards](http://www.corestandards.org/Math) for 6,7 and 8 grade.  The course is remedial in nature, so it would be nice to have instructive resources instead of just practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming because of the interest in technology you are looking for more than just text book references.  I have been trying to use some online resources along with video games to keep my students engaged.

Online resources should be pretty plentiful. You could use [TeacherTube](http://teachertube.com/) to create reference videos that follow the exact curriculum that you want to follow.  You could also use [Kahn Acadamy](http://www.khanacademy.org/), but for my taste the videos are a bit long and boring.  It might work for some students but if you are looking at a remedial group then it might be to boring.

The games that I have tried to implement are [DimentionU](http://educator.dimensionu.com/DimU/default.aspx?) and [The Lost Function](https://www.atltgames.com/products/episodeone/).  I believe that both of these games use the common core standards.

I really didn't like Dimension U very much at all, it doesn't contain any real instruction and although the students did seem to like playing it, I doubt that they were actually learning anything.  I personally don't understand the appeal.

However [The Lost Function](https://www.atltgames.com/products/episodeone/) actually contains quite a bit of instruction and the students seemed to respond really well to it.  It contained a nice balance of instruction and practice.  It allows students to move very quickly through content that the are already comfortable with, and focusing on the areas where they need help, but its all individualized. I actually really like this game.

Comment: Thanks for the resources,  I'll be sure to check them out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://www.khanacademy.org/

This is probably the best there is at the level and context you're looking for.